# Trace for Endomoprhisms of Chain Complexes of Free R-Modules

Tags: category-theory, definition, homology-cohomology, trace

So, I believe that chain complexes of free R-modules are dualizable objects in a symmetric monoidal category $ch(R-mod)$. Thus, one can define a general trace for such objects using the evaluation and coevaluation maps associated with such objects. I have yet to go through the details of this but I was wondering if there was a simple definition for the trace of of endomorphisms of chain complexes of free R-modules, for instance the alternating sum of the traces of the individual maps in each degree? I'm not sure if this lines up with the more general categorical trace or if I have things confused. If anyone could point me to a source or provide a definition I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The following document contains the Hopf Trace Formula which expresses the trace of the chain complexes in terms of the trace of the corresponding homology groups: http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2019/REUPapers/Lin,Edgar.pdf is that what you're looking for?

Comment: It may be and it looks like it agrees with what I was thinking. And I realize I accidentally left detail out of my question so let me update it.